# Booking.com Hotel Management API

Tags: xml, api, booking.com-api

I own a hotel and had a look on booking.com for an API as I want to create my own front end interface to update my hotel room rates / numbers for some days. As well as upload pictures / update the hotel description through that API. However the only thing I could find was an API for affiliates to get Hotels in a certain location with a certain price etc. Would anyone be able to point me in the right direction for this use case or is it not available and would I then have to write a scraper to do this for myself ?

Comment: I am searching for a similar solution.. Please do let us know if you have found any...

Comment: @HarishMohanan you can always write a scraper to programmatically update rates and rooms vacancies.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

**UPDATE 3 - 9th Dec 2017**

It would appear that Booking.com now have [documentation available for their API](https://developers.booking.com/api/index.html?version=2.0), but you need to be [signed up](https://www.booking.com/affiliate-program/v2/index.html) to them as a business in order to get access.

**UPDATE 2 - 8th May 2017**

It seems Booking.com have recently completed some Beta testing for their API, it may looks like they are making it even easier for people to connect. For more information regarding Booking.com's API, have a look [here](https://news.booking.com/bookingcom-launches-new-content-api-for--accommodations-channel-managers-and-content-providers/)

**UPDATE**

Booking.com **DO** have an XML API system, however as many people have stated it is not available to Developers. It is internal and only made available to Hotel/Chains who are apart of their partner system. So **YES** they do, but **NO** it's not publicly available.

**Original Answer**

I can categorically state that at the time of writing, Booking.com do not have an API system, I know this because I've contacted them requesting such info, and they kindly advised me that they do not have an API that is currently available to developers.

Comment: There are at least two third-party channel management services that say they can synchronize via API with booking.com among many other aggregators:  1) http://verticalbooking.com/en/channel_manager.htm
2) http://beds24.com/channel-manager.html

So, presumably, there is a way to interface with booking.com but how to do that directly without a third-party I don't know...

Comment: @brando Perhaps [this](http://www.booking.com/content/affiliate-help.html)? It sounds like the closest thing to an API. Unless those companies have special deals with booking.com, then IDK... (marking another question as a duplicate of this one in the meantime)

Comment: http://www.hotel-spider.com/ channel manager have connection to booking.com and a lot of other IDS and GDS. Worth to check.

Comment: They do have an API but it is closed. They only connect with so called "integration partners".

Comment: You can always write a scraper to programmatically update rates and rooms vacancies.

Comment: If you're looking for a third party application to help manage your rates and availability then take a look at tokeet.com.

Comment: its no API but you can download dataset files if you join their affiliate network. Which is very well available for anyone that joins.

Answer (score 9):

There are at least two third-party channel management services that say they can synchronize via API with booking.com among many other aggregators:
1) http://verticalbooking.com/en/channel_manager.htm

2) http://beds24.com/channel-manager.html

So, presumably, there is a way to interface via API with booking.com but how to do that directly without a third-party I don't know...

Comment: But how do third party channel managers connect to booking api?

Comment: That is a good question.  Don't know the answer but presumably there IS an API for booking.com.

Comment: @brando the API is closed, but you can always write a scraper to programmatically update rates and rooms vacancies.

Answer (score 6):

Booking.com has an API but it is only available to "channel managers". I will not recommend a channel manager here but I will outline what you can do with it and what needs to be done:

- Find a channel manager that connects with Booking.com. There are many factors to consider before you choose one:

  - Some of channel managers charge a flat monthly fee, others charge a "commission" for each booking
- As far as I know, you can only synchronize the following with Booking.com:

  - Per-night rates
  - Per-night inventory count
  - Per-night restrictions such as minimum and maximum length of stay and closed for booking
- Most channel managers will also fetch new bookings from Booking.com. You might then be able to:

  - Poll the channel manager's provided URL every few minutes
  - Ask the channel manager to post new bookings at a designated URL immediately
  - Either way, you will be able to save new bookings in your PMS
  - You can then update your inventory and push new counts to Booking.com

Once you have setup your inventory (rateplan and roomtypes) on Booking.com you will need to do the following:

- Replicate the inventory on the channel manager
- Contact Booking.com and tell them that they need to setup an XML connection with the channel manager. Booking.com will perform initial setup behind the scenes
- Map the channel manager's inventory with Booking.com. A good channel manager will have their staff set things up for you

Finally, you will implement the channel manager's API to push information from your PMS to the channel. The channel will then push that information to Booking.com. You will have to login to the extranet every now and then to make sure all inventory and bookings are synced properly.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think booking.com offers API suitable for your business case. They use various techniques to get you to their booking system (like booking.com buttons) but as far as I know there is no way for common user to automate XML uploads or downloads, to sync your reservation system with booking.com, etc.

Comment: You can always write a scraper to programmatically update rates and rooms vacancies.

Answer (score 2):

There is another 3rd party API that you may check, it is in following  https://rapidapi.com/apidojo/api/booking, I have tested the API and their response data are as same as on the official site. The response are in JSON format. Currently, there are enough APIs end points that you need to query data, such as : Auto complete for locations, list properties with options and filters, get detail rooms, property description, facilities, policies, etc … . Hope this help.

Comment: it is free or paid?

Answer (score 0):

In Booking's admin page, have a look under > channel manager.
I just signed up for a Planyo trial. Looks promising. They have a Booking extension as well.

Comment: Did you have the link please ?

Comment: @Dev'Hamz if you don't want to buy a third-party solution, you can always write a scraper to programmatically update rates and rooms vacancies.

Comment: Planyo is ok, but I think Tokeet.com is better.

Answer (score 0):

You can use NOBEDS API it contains
Airbnb API
Booking API
Expedia API
and more...

All you need is get API key - 10 Eur / month
https://api.nobeds.com