# Get property rating from Booking.com API

Tags: booking.com-api

I need to get the rating value from Booking.com system for specific property. Is there an API that provides information such as overall rating and other useful information for properties that are listed in their system?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Booking.com Hotel Management API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22004435/booking-com-hotel-management-api)

Comment: (Also entirely off-topic here. Contact them and ask.)

Comment: It's not the same like the one you linked. I already review it. They have few APIs for different purposes.

Comment: Then go through the list, or contact them. Your question is off-topic here.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In case anyone has the same question I will answer in short - the booking.com API is not public! In order to get access you need to write them an email and provide a lot of information about why you're going to use it, how and who is going to use it. Describe your business model etc. Also you need to producing an average of 500 bookings per month. Then wait an approval process.

I decided to simple parse the website and get the overall rating.